# Is there a spec for maximum voltage drop to a motor at startup?

Tags: motor, impedance, voltage

When an induction motor starts, it pulls more current than when continuously running. Current flow causes voltage at the terminals to drop. At some point, the voltage drops too low to successfully start the motor. That means that for any given motor there's a maximum source impedance, above which it won't start. Is there a spec or general rule for determining this maximum voltage drop or source impedance?

Comment: But load torque at startup also effects things and so does supplied voltage. And different windings of induction motors have different startup torque curves. That means there's a voltage drop and source impedance for every case, not just one.

Comment: Motors (bigger than handheld) typically spec Full-Load-Amps (FLA) or Locked-Rotor-Amps (LRA) on their nameplate.  These can be used to calculate voltage drop.

Answer (score 1):

There is no spec for a given motor or for induction motors in general. Electric utilities may impose a limit on the voltage sag that a given customer can produce at the point of connection with other customers. Facility managers also need to be aware of the disruption to other equipment that might result from starting a large motor. There may be a rule of thumb that can be found stated in terms like "if a motor's rated current exceeds X percent of the electrical service capacity, you must calculate the effects of starting the motor." Some engine-generator set manufacturer's publish estimates of the maximum motor rating that is advisable.

To do a study of motor starting effects, you must know the nature of the load. A centrifugal fan or pump requires very little running torque at low speed, but experiences an increase in torque proportional to the square of speed. Most other loads require close to the rated motor torque for operation at any speed unless the load can be manually applied once the motor reaches full speed.

You also must know the load inertia. That will determine how long the motor takes to reach full speed, and thus the duration of the voltage sag. Also, if the motor takes too long to come up to speed, in could overheat.

Induction motors that conform to international standards have all the necessary information marked on the rating plate attached to the motor. That includes full-load current (FLA) and a code that designates the maximum multiple of FLA experienced during starting. There will also be an indication of which of several standard torque vs. speed characteristics apply to the motor.

If a study indicates that there may be a problem with starting a particular motor-driven piece of equipment, there are a number of mitigations that can be used.